# Excel macro to consolidate data

Tags: vba, excel

I have many excel files in a folder.

I wanted a macro to iterate through each file and copy sheet named *final cost* and make a sheet with name of source file in destination file.

Like there are three files A, B, C each having a sheet named *"final cost*

The new file will have three sheets named

- A,
- B,
- C

The edited code looks like

```
Sub RunCodeOnAllXLSFiles()
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim wbResults As Workbook
    Dim wbCodeBook As Workbook

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Application.EnableEvents = False

    'On Error Resume Next

    'Set wbCodeBook = ThisWorkbook

    Dim FilePath    As String, fName As String
    Dim aWB As Workbook, sWB As Workbook

    Set aWB = ActiveWorkbook
    FilePath = "D:\binny\" 'change to suit
    fName = Dir(FilePath & "*.xls")

    Do While fName <> ""
        If fName <> aWB.Name Then
            Set sWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FilePath & fName, UpdateLinks:=0)
            sWB.Worksheets("Final Cost").Range("A1:Z6666").Copy
            sWB.Close False
            Sheets.Add.Name = fName
            Worksheets(fName).Range("D1").Select
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:= _
            "Microsoft Word 8.0 Document Object"
        End If
        fName = Dir
    Loop
    Set sWB = Nothing: Set aWB = Nothing


               'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The things now to do are:

1. preserve formatting and cell width
2. I can't get Paste Special to work
3. Delete worksheet with same name if exists

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In order to get quick and reliable answers, you should: first, try to write in plain and full english (you can edit your question with the edit link at the bottom of your question) and show us that you have first tried something because we are not here to do someone else's job (even if we are likely to help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got the most part figured out. Here is what I recommend.

Set a name for 1 main worksheet in the file from where the macro is run so that you can delete all sheets except that one sheet in 1 go. Let's say that the main sheet is "MainSheet"

For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "MainSheet" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Now you can add this code to the beginning of your code. I have modified your code. All I am doing in your code is after the sheet is created, simply delete the columns after Z.

See this (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub test()
    Dim FilePath As String, fName As String
    Dim aWB As Workbook, sWB As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ColName As String

    Set aWB = ThisWorkbook

    '~~> Delete sheets
    For Each ws In aWB.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "MainSheet" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next ws

    FilePath = "D:\binny\" '<~~ Change to suit

    fName = Dir(FilePath & "*.xls")

    Do While fName <> ""
        If fName <> aWB.Name Then
            Set sWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilePath & fName, UpdateLinks:=0)
            sWB.Sheets("Final Cost").Move after:=aWB.Sheets(aWB.Sheets.Count)
            sWB.Close False
            '~~> The sheet is copied, simply delete the columns after Z
            With aWB.Sheets(aWB.Sheets.Count)
                .Name = fName
                .Cells.Copy
                .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                '~~> Get the last column Name
                ColName = Split(.Cells(, .Columns.Count).Address, "$")(1)
                .Columns("AA:" & ColName).Delete
            End With
        End If
        fName = Dir
    Loop
    Set sWB = Nothing: Set aWB = Nothing
End Sub
```

Give it a try and if you get any errors, let me know which line and I will rectify it.

Comment: I haven't tested your code but I have worked with entire different approach. Actually The columns after Z have data needed for calculations. and if it is deleted then formulas will show error. SO what I have done is paste by value. I am sharing my code below. I am just having problem with PasteSpecial fuction and lost formatting, cell width, etc and deletion of sheets before adding new which you have already answered

Comment: I am really impressed by your devotion to edit questions and answer - nice code btw

Comment: @user1568701: You didn't mention that there were formulas :) All you have to do is add two more line to the code that I gave. See the updated code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even I didn't know their were formulas. I am more used to JAVA and C/C++. This is for a cousin who is in finance background and bragged about his computer skills.

Comment: I am getting two errors. ws.Delete and .PasteSpecial xlValues method fail

Comment: NO I used it as it is. to be exact the error says Run-time error 1004  Method 'Delete' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: Do you have a sheet called "Mainsheet" like I suggested? I just tested the delete code and it is working just fine.

Comment: Hey it works. Thanks a ton. Actually i created a sheet named MainSheet and it worked. Now just one thing. I am getting this error...A formula or sheet you want to move or copy already contains the name 'stdRate' which already exists on destination worksheet . Do you want to use this version of name. I want to suppress this message or choose yes by default

Comment: Add `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` just before `sWB.Sheets("Final Cost").Move after:=aWB.Sheets(aWB.Sheets.Count)` and add `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` after that :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806731/vba-macr0-to-iterate-through-sheets-and-copy-specific-data-to-specific-cells