# Best way to compile data from thousands of Excel files into one Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have thousands of excel files all formatted exactly the same, and all located within the same folder on our server.

What I'm attempting to do is pull specific data from each one of those individual excel files and compile them into a single excel file located in a different location on our server. Preferably in an Excel Table which can be sorted, filtered, etc.

Does anybody know what the easiest way to achieve this would be?

It would also be ideal to have this "Single Excel File" solution include the ability to "auto update" anytime a new file is added onto the other thousands.

To put this in more general terms...

I'm trying to make a home brew Purchase Order system. We already have thousands of individual Purchase Orders created over the years, and currently do a "Save-As" on the most recent one to create the next.

What we now need is an ability to consolidate specific pieces of data within those individual PO files into a new, (hopefully auto updating) PO Log file.

I apologize if this doesn't make sense. And I appreciate any and all help/ideas that any of you may have.

---

**UPDATE:** Below you will find what I have been currently doing to try and achieve what I'm asking for an easier solution to.

I've got a Workbook that has been built to gather/pull data from, what has turned out to be, hundreds and hundreds (and growing) of different closed Workbooks. It's basically a Purchase Order Log that automatically gathers the data from the individual Purchase Orders as they are created.

This PO Log Workbook is a table with 8 columns, A:H.

Column A has the following formula in it.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISERROR(INDEX(FL,ROW()-2)),"",INDEX(FL,ROW()-2)),".xlsx","")
```

Where "FL" is a Name substitution for the folder location to our individual Purchase Order files. As the formula indicates, it searches that folder location for any existing or new files in that folder, then transfers that file name, minus the extension (.xlsx), into the respective row within Column A.

It is this retrieved data in Column A that drives the remaining formulas located in the remaining columns (B:H). Those remaining formulas all look exactly the same, with exception to the specific cell that they are requesting data from. Columns B:H have the following formula in them.

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT.EXT("'\\MyPath\["&$A3&".xlsx"&"]Purchase Order'!F9"),"")
```

You'll notice that this formula is looking for a file named whatever is in Column A's respective cell +.xlsx. Once that file is located, it is looking for data in Cell F9. Every remaining column is looking for data in a different cell(s), but the rest of the formula remains the same.

That's the meat and potatoes of what should be a very simple Workbook.

What has happened overtime though is that we now have over a thousand individual files that this Workbook is looking into, and it's resulting in exponentially increased calculation times. Right now, we have to wait a little over 30 minutes for our PO Log file to update. And that amount of time is increasing as more and more individual PO files are created.

Comment: What is preventing you from achieving this?  You've stated what you want to do, but not what you've tried, what problems you ran into, etc.  There are dozens of similar questions here on SO (with answers) which would help you make a start on this.  E.g.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789478/excel-macro-to-consolidate-data

Comment: I was hesitant on sharing the process that I had put together myself in hopes that I could avoid influencing anybody with a different solution for me. I will try and briefly describe my current debilitating setup at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: If the problem is ever-increasing recalculation time, aren't there old PO's which will no longer ever be updated, and can you not copy/paste-special-values those formulas on the "master" sheet, instead of re-reading every single file when you recalculate?  Are you looking for a VBA solution? If you store both the filename and the last-updated date you would be able to catch up only new/updated files when you refresh.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if there is another solution for this which might greatly decrease the calculation time. But yes, there are old PO's littered throughout which I could essentially remove the formulas from. But also, at any given time, at least 500, or more of those PO's stay active, and would need to be kept up to date within the Automated PO Log (Master File). In response to your ending comment, Yes, the filename and last updated date are available to be retrieved. ****I greatly appreciate your time Tim. I've been scouring numerous websites and forums all day looking for solutions.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way? Maybe there's a way to achieve this at the individual PO file level? Could I possibly web some code, via VBA/Macro, into the individual PO files so that whenever a new PO file is created, it can then "push" that data to an existing (growing) table in the PO Log (Master)? Or also, update any pre-existing values previously associated into that Master excel table? Whereas right now, I'm basically "pulling" into there. I don't know. My brain hurts right now. :/

Comment: Once you add code into your PO template then you run the risk of needing to update that code across potentially hundreds of separate files.  There are a few ways you could get around that (such as putting all the code in an add-in which the PO template would load up whenever you open it).  However I think you could continue with your current "pull" and switch instead to using a VBA-driven approach. If I find time later I will post something you can use to get started.

Comment: Tim Williams, thank you so much!! Fixing this growing (calculation time) Automated PO Log file has been on my To-Do list for months now. Today was my day dedicated to getting it solved. 7 hours later, I'm here chatting with you. Anytime that you are so graciously able to put into helping me with this, does not go unnoticed with the karma gods. All joking aside, Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - see below. This worked for me with a small test set of files.  Hopefully you can see where you'll need to update it for your setup.

Paste this code in a regular VBA module, and add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (in the VB editor >> Tools >> References)

**EDIT**: tweaked to use file name without extension. Note though: this could lead to problems if you have two files with the same name but one is *.xls and the other is *.xlsx

```
Sub RefreshMasterList()

    Const SRC_FOLDER As String = "C:\_Stuff\test\"
    Const COL_FNAME As Long = 1
    Const COL_LAST_MOD As Long = 2

    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fold As Scripting.Folder, fl As Scripting.File
    Dim f As Range, sht As Worksheet, rw As Range, dtlm
    Dim getInfo As Boolean, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim baseName As String

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")

    'clear all file status flag colors
    sht.Columns(COL_FNAME).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    Set fold = fso.GetFolder(SRC_FOLDER)
    For Each fl In fold.Files
        If fl.Name Like "*.xls*" Then
            getInfo = False
            dtlm = Format(fl.DateLastModified, "yyyy-mm-dd-hh:mm:ss")
            baseName = fso.GetBaseName(fl.Name)

            'have this file already ?
            Set f = sht.Columns(1).Find(baseName, lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                         LookIn:=xlValues)
            If f Is Nothing Then 'not already listed...
                Set rw = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, COL_FNAME).End(xlUp) _
                                    .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
                With rw
                    .Cells(COL_FNAME).Value = baseName
                    'flag new
                    .Cells(COL_FNAME).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                    .Cells(COL_LAST_MOD).Value = dtlm
                End With
                getInfo = True
            Else
                Set rw = f.EntireRow
                If rw.Cells(COL_LAST_MOD).Value < dtlm Then
                    Debug.Print f.Cells(COL_LAST_MOD).Value, dtlm
                    'flag updated
                    rw.Cells(COL_FNAME).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    rw.Cells(COL_LAST_MOD).Value = dtlm
                    getInfo = True
                Else
                    'flag no change
                    rw.Cells(COL_FNAME).Interior.Color = RGB(220, 220, 220)
                End If
            End If

            If getInfo Then 'need to add/update from this file?
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fl.Path, , True)
                With wb.Sheets("Purchase Order")
                    rw.Cells(3).Value = .Range("F9").Value
                    rw.Cells(4).Value = .Range("F10").Value
                    'etc...
                End With
                wb.Close False 'don't save...
            End If

        End If
    Next fl
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! I tweaked this to fit my needs, and it seems to be working great. I updated the code to reflect my cells more accordingly. I have a question tho, how can I force the data to begin entering at A3 (R3C1) on my Master? Reason being is that I have a pre-formatted Excel Table there with Headers, etc. So that it can auto calculate total costs based on filtering values set. Is this something that is easy to do?

Comment: If this something that is too cumbersome, please don't worry about it. You've already helped me out a ton, for which I am forever grateful. :)

Comment: Oh, one other thing... is it possible to remove the file extension from the copied file name that is placed into Column A, within the VBA?

Comment: See my edit for using the file base name (no extension). As long as you have a header in A2 then data will start at A3, since it just looks for the first empty cell in the "filename" column.

Comment: About having it start in R3C1... I decided to select the values and moved them into the table myself. I then ran that module again, and it seemed to have recognized that I moved the data because it grayed out all the file names which were once green, but in a different location. So I guess I should be good to go with that? I may just have to stay on top of how many rows I have left in my table so that I can drag it down before before running the RefreshMaster routine. Or would my table auto-expand on its own if the values get to the point to where it needs more rows?

Comment: I don't use tables, so I can't answer those questions. As for maving rows around, it just goes by the filename+date when checking for updates, so you can re-order rows without any problem.  If you need you can always do a full refresh by deleting all the data and running the macro.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! Last question... where do I send the Starbucks Giftcard? ;)

Comment: BTW, you've absolutely inspired me to become more versed in VBA. Thank you for being this nobody's inspiration.