# Search for specific workbook to consolidate data from several files into one

Tags: excel

I've created an audit form, which has to be filled with all details and there will be results based on the details, which I would like to consolidate in one file.
I've got over 300 different workbooks all defined by the name of the audited party.

How can I extract specific values from each of these files based on the name of the file? Is it possible to use VLOOKUP for the location of the file, so it'll search certain values if the file with the corresponding name is placed in the located folder?

*I'm sorry for my somewhat vague description, but I hope this image somewhat clarifies what I'm looking for*

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22544899/4961700